# Non-interpreted PHP after <select>

Tags: php, html

I've got this code :

```
    $sql='SELECT Jour_depart, Jour_livraison FROM jourdepartca WHERE inactif=0';
                                       [...]

    echo"<select name='liste'>";

    $jours = array('Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi');
    $mois = array('Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre');

    if(!empty($list))
    {

        foreach ($list as $data)
        {      
            $jourstr = date('w',strtotime($data['Jour_livraison']));
            $jourint = date('j',strtotime($data['Jour_livraison']));
            $moisstr = date('n',strtotime($data['Jour_livraison']))-1;
            $annee = date('Y',strtotime($data['Jour_livraison']));
            $datecomplete = $jours[$jourstr]." ".$jourint." ".$mois[$moisstr]." ".$annee;

            echo"<option value='".$data['Jour_depart']."'>".$datecomplete."</option>";                        
        }
    }
    else 
    {

        echo"<option>Aucune date disponible, merci de nous contacter</option>";
    }

    echo"</select>";
```

My problem is that my php stop being interpreted after this line :

```
echo "<select name=liste>"
```

For information my query is good and works since i checked it with json_encode($myArray) so it do not come from that.

Comment: What happens after that line? Do you have any error code? checked your error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is Fine you have to check how are implementing it in your project /framework.

Answer (score -1):

Spotted the error.

I was trying to retrieve data from an array since mysql send it like that, but since i was using Joomla i had to retrieve it from an object.